# Memory alignment and C arrays

Tags: arrays, memory, char

I have a big char array that contains words that are used as map keys. For e.g. "key11 key12 .."
If I consume the key12 from the array directly, would it be considered that I am using misaligned memory as the address of key12 is not divisible by word size?

I do not know how memory alignment works when we use c strings. The starting address could be  perfectly aligned but if we skip the first index of c string then(in my opinion) it becomes mis aligned. If that were the case then any c string compare function will have to work with a lot of misaligned addresses. Somehow feel that I am missing something here. .

Comment: Generally memory alignment is not something you need to think about unless you  are doing evil or hacky things on the heap. When you malloc a char*, the act of either casting it to char* or storing it in a char* causes it to be aligned to char, or 1 byte indicies.

Answer (score 1):

If you have something lets say

```
char *keys = "key11 key12 key13"
```

the best way to get each of them is to use

```
char *token = strtok(keys, " \n");
```

now token is a pointer to the "key11" and if you call

```
token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
```

you will get the pointer to the next key.

you can read [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) more about strtok()

Comment: Ervin, I am not asking how to use strtok. But instead in a way asking if using strtok here leads to misalignment of char arrays.